# Can't connect on wifi

Tags: wifi, drivers

I have a tp link archer t2uh usb wifi dongle. I can't make it work. I tried to find a solution online, but I never used linux before. I really need help with this. I don't want to give up on linux just yet...

Comment: check this website [Ubuntu Linux TP-Link version 2 WiFi driver install](http://brilliantlyeasy.com/ubuntu-linux-tl-wn725n-tp-link-version-2-wifi-driver-install/)

Comment: Didn't work. The solution requires intenet connection. I don't have it. Neither usb or bluetooth tethering with my phone doesn't work.

Comment: Does your PC have Ethernet?